# c# winform application resolution issue?

Tags: c#

I have to use resolution class so which namespace is needed to include this class in vs 2008 in C#?

```
Resolution.CResolution
```

I cannot find this.

Comment: marc_s comment is valid.  When asking questions provide more details.  It is by pure accident that someone knows what you are talking about.

Answer (score 3):

It would seem you have been reading an article associated with some custome class the a developer has created.

The Resolution.CResolution is not part of the .net FrameWork.

I have however found this link http://blog.stevienova.com/2005/01/08/net-changing-screen-resolution/ where that class is refferenced.

You would need to download the DLL and reference the library in whatever solution your building

Answer (score 2):

The given namespace is not part of .NET framework. That seems to be part of code from example shown here:
http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/09/how-to-change-the-screen-resolution-in-c/

What you need to do is integrate the namespace/files from the example there and then you will be able to import it.

Kind reqards,
Bo

Comment: the specified link code,using in  my application but resolution.cresoluton  is not found  and i am using vs 2008

Comment: Guatham, the class is listed in Resolution.cs (just add that .cs file to your project) : **namespace Resolution
{
   public class CResolution
    {**

Comment: Accept answer if it is working for you.